# Probability that mean is larger than median

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, order-statistics

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d random variables taking values in $\mathbb{R}$.
Suppose that $n$ is odd and the $X_i$ follow a continuous distribution.
I am interested in the probability that the mean of these random variables is larger than their median, i.e.
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i>X_{\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}
\right]
$$
My guess is that in general, there is no nice formula for this probability.
But I wonder:
Are there (easy or known) special cases, where there is a (nice) formula?

Comment: The easy case is a symmetric continuous distribution, where it is $\frac 12$

Comment: On the other hand, for [Pareto distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) with shape parameter $\alpha$ approaching $0$, even for $n=3$ this seems to approach $1$.

Comment: In the title, for clarification, I think that the mean and median need to be replaced by "sample mean" and "sample median", respectively, because the mean and median are also defined for the distribution, differing from the related ones defined for the sample.

Comment: @Henry could please you provide a formal proof for the symmetric case. I provided a proof below for the uniform distribution and large samples. How can this be extended for all symmetric densities?

Comment: @AmirAhmadiJavid If the distribution is symmetric about $m$ then consider $Y_i=2m-X_i$ so $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$ has the same distribution as  $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$.   You get $\mathbb{P}\left[
\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i>X_{\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}
\right]=\mathbb{P}\left[
\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^nY_i <Y_{\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}
\right]=\mathbb{P}\left[
\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i<X_{\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}
\right]$ and, since (from the continuous distribution) the probability of equality is $0$, the sum of the first and last is $1$ and each must then be $\frac12$.

Comment: @Henry thank you for the nice proof!

Answer (score 3):

The probability can be calculated whenever the distribution of $X_1,\dots,X_n$ is absolutely continuous (we have a PDF).

Note that we can rewrite the probability as
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i>X_{\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}\right]= \mathbb{P}\left[Z_n:=\sum_{i=1}^nX_{(i)}-nX_{\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}>0\right].
$$
$Z_n$ is a linear combination of order statistics, where the weights differ  for even and odd $n$ considering the definition of $X_{\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}$. For absolutely continuous distribution, the joint distribution of all order statics is explicitly known, so the distribution of $Z_n$ can be determined. The probability can be computed by integration.

**Symmetric distributions**

For the uniform distribution on [0,1], a closed-form formula for the CDF of an arbitrary linear combination of ordered statistics is provided in [1](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-42/issue-2/The-Distribution-of-Linear-Combinations-of-Order-Statistics-from-the/10.1214/aoms/1177693419.full). For odd $n$, we have $$-Z_n=-X_{(1)}-X_{(2)} \dots +(n-1) X_{(\frac{n+1}{2})}+\dots-X_{(n)}, $$ and using (2.2) in [1](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-42/issue-2/The-Distribution-of-Linear-Combinations-of-Order-Statistics-from-the/10.1214/aoms/1177693419.full), the probability is

$$\mathbb{P}\left[-Z_n\le 0\right]=1-\sum_{j=1 }^{\frac{n+1}{2}} \frac{c_j^{n-1}}{ \prod_{i \neq j}(c_j-c_i)) }  $$

with

$$ c_j= j-1  \text{  for  }  j\in \left\{1, \dots, \frac{n+1}{2} \right\}$$

$$ c_j= j-(n+1)\text{  for  }j\in \left\{\frac{n+1}{2} +1, \dots, n\right\}.$$

I computed the above for $n=3,5 \text{ and } 7$ and realized that it was always 1/2. For the uniform distribution I can prove that $-Z_n$ has a symmetric distribution. In [1](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-42/issue-2/The-Distribution-of-Linear-Combinations-of-Order-Statistics-from-the/10.1214/aoms/1177693419.full), a representation of $-Z_n$ is given by

$$-Z_n \sim c_1X_1+c_2X_2+\dots+c_nX_n$$

with $c_1,\dots,c_n$ defined above. As all $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent and have symmetric distributions, then $-Z_n$ has a symmetric distribution. Furthermore, considering $\sum_{j=1}^{n}c_j=0$, the mean of $-Z_n$ is zero, and hence, the probability is always $\frac{1}{2}$.

I am not sure whether this can be generalized to all symmetric densities or not. Indeed, we can simply see that the sample mean and the sample median (for odd $n$) both have symmetric distributions, but it does not imply that  their difference $-Z_n$ also has a symmetric distribution because they are dependent.

For **any** symmetric distributions, by the method presented by @Henry in a comment above, without using the distributional symmetry of $-Z_n$, it can be shown that the probability is $\frac{1}{2}$.

**Large samples**

Moreover, under some conditions, $Z_n$ converges to a normal distribution. In fact, for a density with finite variance, the asymptotic joint distribution of sample mean and a sample quantile follows a bivariate normal distribution (see [2](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etom/papers/unpublished/meanmed.pdf) for more details).

Hence, as $n \rightarrow \infty$ the probability converges to

$$ \Phi \left(\frac{\mu-m}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \left(\sigma^2+\frac{1}{4f(m)^2}-\frac{\mathbb{E} \left(|X-m| \right)}{f(m)} \right)}} \right) $$

where $\Phi$ is the CDF of standard normal and where $f$, $\mu$, $m$, and $\sigma^2$ are the density, mean, median, and variance of the distribution of $X$, respectively.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and the useful references!

Comment: You are very welcome! I just added more details.